# Elasticsearch: Parameter “include” isn’t case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I configure the index in elasticsearch in order to make the parameter "include" from the aggregation to be case insensitive?

```
I have this index:

    PUT index {"settings":
              {"analysis": {
              "analyzer": {
                "my_normalizer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "keyword",
                  "char_filter": ,
                  "filter": ["lowercase"]}}}},
                "mappings":{
                  "_doc":{
                   "properties":{
                       "foo": {
                         "type": "text",
                         "analyzer": "my_normalizer",
                         "fielddata": true}}}}}
With data:


       PUT index/_doc/1 {
           "foo": "BAR"
             }
       PUT index/_doc/2 {
           "foo": "bar"
             }

And the query:

    GET index/_search{
         "size": 0,
          "aggs": {
             "ad":{
               "terms": {"field": "foo",
               "include": "ba.*"}}}}
```

But if i change "ba" in "BA" the aggregation has no result.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in a terms aggregation the term you supply is not being analyzed, so when you supply `BA` there it is not lower cased by ES. The application should lowercase the terms you supply in the aggregation. This is assuming you want case insensitive results. If you want case sensitive results (different results for `BA` and `ba`) you should not use a lower-casing analyzer in the first place.